# Reading data issue meanwhile updating and/or writing on Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I am new to DB and I needed it for a project.My problem is as follows: I have 3 scripts that write to Postgres DB and another script that does updates on it. So far, with that I haven't had any issues. However, now I need to read that data at the same time. More specifically from that DB, I need to read last 1 min data meanwhile. And I have another script for that. But, when I run this script, I can't see any writes from the scripts that is supposed to write. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your other scripts haven't `COMMIT`ed their data yet, which means that their updates aren't visible to your queries yet.